# Formula para anidar varias condiciones en Excel

Tags: excel

Tengo un problema con una formula en excel, quiero hacer una condición que diga

> "Si promedio >=80 y Conducta >=8 ='Aprobado'
>
> Si promedio <80 ó Conducta <8 ='Recuperacion'
>
> Si promedio <80 y Conducta <8 ='Reprobado'"

llevo muchos intentos y no me sale.

```
=SI(Y(C7>=80; D7>=8;"APROBADO"; SI(Y(C7<80; D7<8;"REPROBADO"; SI(Y(C7<80; D7>=8;"RECUPERACION";SI(Y(C7>=80; D7<8;"RECUPERACION")))))))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por más que he visto videos no le doy, Agradezco cualquier tipo de ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Siguiendo el planteamiento de los enunciados en su orden, no vas a tener ningún reprobado ya que el segundo enunciado *Si promedio <80 ó Conducta <8 ='Recuperacion'* anularía el tercero por tratarse de una condicional OR *si se cumple una o la otra condición*.

Prueba alterando un poco el orden de las condiciones, tal que:

```
=SI(Y(C7>=80;D7>=8);"APROBADO";SI(Y(C7<80;D7<8);"REPROBADO";SI(O(C7<80;D7<8);"RECUPERACION";"FUERA DE INTERVALOS")))
```

- En primer lugar se validan los rangos para aprobar
- En segundo lugar se validan los rangos para reprobar
- La última validación sería el enunciado para recuperar
- Al final pones un resultado *opcional* si ninguna validación se cumple

Comment: Es verdad, lo tenia mal planteado. La formula que me has pasado me resulto a la perfección, solo tuve que cambiar todos los ; por , Ali si me agarró.
Gracias @DjCrazy

Comment: Es verdad, los separadores dependen de la configuración regional de tu computadora. Te pasé la fórmula con punto y coma por el ejemplo que pusiste en la pregunta, pero es completamente válido tu comentario. Me alegra que te funcione. Éxitos!